# Prove $f:N\rightarrow N$, $f(x,y)=2^{x-1}(2y-1)$ is surjective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Prove $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ $f(x,y)=2^{x-1}(2y-1)$ is surjective.

I tried to show it's surjective by proving $2^{x-1}$ and $2y-1$ are surjective then their product should be surjective as well, but when I tried to get the inverses the numbers ended up not being natural numbers cause $log_2(x)+1$ is the inverse of $2^{x-1}$ and $\frac{y+1}2$ is the inverse of 2y-1, but we can see they don't fit into the domain of natural numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: As Dave points out, you are asking whether every positive integer is a product of an odd number and a power of two. I suggest (strong) induction.

Comment: In simple wording, express a number in the form $2^{x-1}(2y-1)$ simply means we keep dividing the number by $2$ until it becomes odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that any positive integer can be written (uniquely) as $2^n k$ where $n\geq 0$ and $k$ is odd. For fun: the uniqueness shows that $f$ is also injective.

Also, I will say that a product of surjective functions need not be surjective. Indeed, consider $h_1,h_2:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $h_1(x):=h_2(x):=x$, which are clearly surjective, but $h_1h_2(x)=x^2$ is not surjective.

Comment: I'm having trouble bridging the gap between how that shows that $2^{x-1}(2y-1)$ must be mapped to an x,y thus making it surjective. I sort of see how it could be applicable though.

Comment: Take $x,y\in\mathbb N$ (positive integers). Then, by my note, $x=2^nk$ for some $n\geq 0$ and odd $k$, and $y=2^ml$ for some $m\geq 0$ and odd $l$. Then $k=2k'-1$ for some $k'\in\mathbb N$ and $l=2l'-1$ for some $l'\in\mathbb N$ by definition of odd. Do you see how to finish?

Comment: sorry not really? I assumed plug those values for x and y into $2^{x-1}(2y-1)$?

Comment: Excuse me, my previous comment was misleading. I meant to just write $x=2^nk$ for $n\geq 0$ and $k$ odd (forget about $y$!). Then $k=2k'-1$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$. Now consider $f(n+1,k')$.

Comment: did you mean consider $f(n+1,k)$? Cause $k'$ might not be a natural number depending on k.

Comment: No it should be $k'$ because we want $f$ to send $k'$ to $2k'-1=k$. We do indeed know that $k'$ is a natural number (uniquely) depending on $k$ (which in turn (uniquely) depends on $x$).